# Should I ask for a new package or package revision

Tags: professionalism, communication, united-kingdom, contracts

I was recently hired on a 3 months contract *(sort of a probation period, I successfully passed through)*, which is now going to be a permanent position with a new contract for me to sign. There was such talk when the CEO congratulated me about how good it had gone and my manager was really happy as well.

**Should I ask** in my response *(email)* that with the new contract for a review of the package as well, or will I be shooting myself in the foot?

a little background, I was jobless for 3 months after I was laid off during my last probation period (due to health and commute being too long which affected my work).

I study on my own, and am not supported by the office, I have a young child who starts nursery next month, and next month I would also start the new contract. Is it time to ask, or will it give a bad impression as me being greedy?  Would they reasonably cut me loose?

And if I ask, How should it be phrased?

Comment: during interview, did you hear "this is a temp job with an option to extend it to full-time contract"? Also, i think it is OK to consider their offer, not sign it right away, as you would do with any other job offer.

Comment: @aaaaaa during interview, they said "lets take this as a contract and see how it goes". The problem is they have review every year and they would be outsourcing more people in future but i am part of core team.

Answer (score 1):

**Should I ask for a new package or package revision**

-> No, because as you mentionned it you only finish the probation time.

3 month is a very short time in a company, even if you did a very good job don't ask for a raise before 1 year ( that is my rule of thumb). Because in the next 9 month a lot can happen, and your boss have currenlty an **idea** of your value but after 1 year of work he will be **certain** of your value and he will be be more likely to approve a raise if he thinks you are really worth it.

Also, after only 3 months you are not crucial to the company, but after 1 year you might be; you will have more leverage after 1 year.

If you ask a raise now, i would say it is unlikely that they fired you, but it will surely give the wrong impression.

Comment: The contract is suppose to end mid next month and they t due to give me a new contract. So this one become void.

Comment: If there is a new contract then maybe you can try, maybe try to have a face to face with your boss and try to see his reaction.

Answer (score 0):

I feel for you, being in a tight situation, without counter-offers (and it seems you like the job). In normal circumstances, for people with good professional relationships, it seems OK to ask for raise/review once in a while, and especially just before accepting offer. Asking/negotiating (unless things go violent) should not be a reason to think you are greedy, or let you go.

It seems that you will be signing new contract, for which usually it is expected to have some negotiation.

Also, you need to see things with the company's point of view:

> they have a good, **proven** worker, they already invested in hiring and training. Note, that they don't know about your life situation (no jobs for a while, child, stress etc). They see professional, they want to continue working with.

It seems reasonable that you didn't negotiate too much over the short-term contract. But now, as you've invested yourself in the job, you are in a position to review offered conditions. Your contract will take year of your life, you should invest into making the best decision.